# How to generate 10 million unique numbers quickly Groovy/Java

Tags: java, groovy

The code below has taken 5 hours to get 1m done lol this is way too slow.

```
int numbers = 10000000
int count = 0
def data = []
File file = new File("out.txt")

while (count < numbers) {
    def number = makeNumber(numbers)
    if (!data.contains(number)) {
        print count + ':Adding ' + number + '\n'
        data << number
        count++
    }
}

for (i in data) {
    print 'Appending ' + i + '\n'
    file.append(i + '\n')
}

String makeNumber(numbers) {
    def range = "83"
    return range + (new Random().nextInt(20000000) + numbers)
}
```

I am currently trying out `java.security.SecureRandom` as in [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328822/generating-10-digits-unique-random-number-in-java) to generate the numbers but its an unknown API to me so it is going slow. A lot of other options aren't guaranteeing uniqueness or speed. I have the uniqueness down I'm pretty sure of that but the speed (please can you throw me some ideas to speed this up? I was thinking sending to other threads but I'd hit the same problem won't I?).

Comment: Write to the file in larger chunks.

Comment: Tangential: if these are numbers why make them strings? Numeric comparisons will be faster than string comparisons. If adding an "83" prefix is a thing, but not directly related to anything else, that can be done on number retrieval *(as opposed to during generation/de-duping/etc)*.

Comment: Other simple improvements: don't create new `Random` instances all the time - you only need one. Don't print to stdout

Comment: Also tangential: naming a number `numbers` is confusing, and it's being used for two different things here. I'd consider naming it `numToGenerate` or `maxNumbers` or sthng; you can still re-use it as a constant to add to each generated number, but IMO it's funky.

Comment: Another possibility if you have the memory : create a massive list of consecutive numbers, shuffle it and delete from it until you have the quantity of numbers required

Comment: ooo - I didnt know about Set :) I wont have to iterate over the object, but I still need a minimum 10m entries so i need to change the loop to make sure its filled
Let me remove that new instance, I'm sure that'll save me some memory too thanks and i will try adding the '83' (yes its required) when adding to the file too. @g00se, you just saved me alot of time I can even do that directly in bash lol

Comment: wow am I impressed with sets its taken less than 10minutes on first go!!! thank you - I will post a fully working answer tonight :)

Comment: Explain the "83".

Comment: @BasilBourque all numbers must start with 83, 82 or 81 - its a business requirement

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 20_000_000).distinct().limit(10_000_000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

In Java syntax:

```java
List < String > range =
        IntStream
                .range ( 10_000_000 , 20_000_000 )   // Generate a sequence of all desired values, rather than generate random numbers.
                .mapToObj ( ( int i ) -> "83" + i )  // Convert from `int` primitive to `String` object, and prepend "83". 
                .collect ( Collectors.toCollection ( ArrayList :: new ) );
Collections.shuffle ( range , random );
Files.write ( Paths.get ( "/tmp/numbers.txt" ) , range );
```

Executes in  **2-3 seconds** on a laptop computer.

Or we can try this nifty nearly-one-liner based on [Comment by Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962253/how-to-generate-10-million-unique-numbers-quickly-groovy-java/76964692#comment135678209_76962253). But this takes longer, upwards of twice as long at 3.5 to 4.5 seconds.

```java
try
{
    Files.write (
            Paths.get ( "/tmp/numbers.txt" ) ,
            SecureRandom
                    .getInstance( "NativePRNG" )
                    .ints ( 0 , 20_000_000 )
                    .distinct ( )
                    .limit ( 10_000_000 )
                    .mapToObj ( ( int i ) -> "83" + i )
                    .toList ( )
    );
}
catch ( IOException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
```

## Generate a sequence of numbers, not random numbers

Apparently you want ten million numbers between ten million and twenty million. Notice that means simply the range *from* 10,000,000 and 20,000,000.  Your range of possible values equates to your range of desired results. So we can start by assembling a sequence of ten-twenty million.

We use `IntStream.range` to assemble the sequence of numbers as a stream of `int` values.

You said you want to treat each number as text, and prepend the text `"83"`. So we use `Stream::map` to convert each number to text along with the prepend.

I do not yet know Groovy, so I'll use Java syntax.

```java
List < String > range =
        IntStream
                .range ( 10_000_000 , 20_000_000 )
                .mapToObj ( ( int i ) -> "83" + i ) 
                .collect ( Collectors.toCollection ( ArrayList :: new ) );
```

Report first and last values to verify.

```java
System.out.println ( range.get ( 0 ) + " - " + range.get ( range.size ( ) - 1 ) );
```

And you want this sequence of ten million strings in random order. So call `Collections.shuffle` to re-order them randomly. No need to generate random numbers.

```java
Collections.shuffle ( range );
```

Report first and last values to verify.

```java
System.out.println ( range.get ( 0 ) + " - " + range.get ( range.size ( ) - 1 ) );
```

When run:

```
8310000000 - 8319999999
8315634260 - 8311372639
```

### Strong random number generator

If you need a more cryptographically strong random number generator than provided by default to perform the shuffle, you can pass an alternate source of randomness. This can be `Random` or any subclass, including `SecureRandom`. For example:

```java
Collections.shuffle ( 
    range , 
    SecureRandom.getInstance( "DRBG" ) 
);
```

I am no expert on random number generators. But I am guessing these  may be of interest to you:

- [*JEP 273: DRBG-Based SecureRandom Implementations*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/273)
- [*JEP 123: Configurable Secure Random-Number Generation*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/123)
- [*What actual algorithm is used by SecureRandom.getInstance("DRBG")?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58304220/642706)

I gather from those documents that via the [Java Service provider interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) and [`SecureRandomSpi`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandomSpi.html) class, you can plug in third-party generator implementations in addition to the new-and-improved ones bundled with some JDKs.

### Write file

And you said you need to write these to a file. The `List` of strings is itself an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html). So we can merely pass to [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Iterable,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)), a method in the Java NIO package of modern file-handling classes.

```java
try
{
    Files.write (
            Paths.get ( "/tmp/numbers.txt" ) ,
            range
    );
}
catch ( IOException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
}
```

The resulting file is 110 MB in size.

### Performance

You will need a bit of free memory to run the code above. We create all the data in memory before writing to storage. I would guess it takes about 200 to 300 MB of RAM, given the file size reported above.

You have a concern about speed of execution. So let's run it once, then run several times to get an average of elapsed time. For more serious benchmarking, use [JMH](https://openjdk.org/jeps/230).

```java
app.randomWrite ( );

int repetitions = 10;
List < Duration > durations = new ArrayList <> ( repetitions );
for ( int index = 0 ; index < repetitions ; index++ ) durations.add ( app.randomWrite ( ) );
System.out.println ( "durations = " + durations );
```

When run on an Apple MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Pro chip, 16 GB memory, and internal solid-state storage, the execution times are around 2.5 seconds, in a range of 2-3 seconds.

```
durations = [PT2.501965458S, PT2.315898625S, PT2.398674875S, PT2.24017325S, PT2.047942S]
```

Answer (score 3):

the following groovy code takes ~ 2.5 seconds to generate 10 million unique integers

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
Set<Integer> generateUniqueNumbers(int count, int bound=20000000, SplittableRandom rnd = new SplittableRandom()) {
    Set<Integer> data = new HashSet<Integer>(count)
    while(data.size() < count){
        data.add( rnd.nextInt(bound) )
    }
    return data
}

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def writeToFile(Set<Integer> data, String path){
    new File(path).withWriter("UTF-8"){w->
        data.each{i-> w.append('83').append(i.toString()).append('\n')}
    }
}


def t = System.currentTimeMillis()
def data  = generateUniqueNumbers(10000000)
println data.size()
println "generate time = ${System.currentTimeMillis() - t} millis"

//writing to file
t = System.currentTimeMillis()
writeToFile(data, "/11/out.txt")
println "write time = ${System.currentTimeMillis() - t} millis"
```

result:

```
10000000
generate time = 2636 millis
write time = 2182 millis
```

if the order of generated numbers is important - you can use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`, but this will increase execution time by ~ x2 - x3

note `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` annotation - always try to use it in groovy when performance is important and you have a large/long loop...

**UPD:** used `SplittableRandom` instead of `Random` because it's faster

**UPD2:** added write to file approach using writer. the implementation in original question `File.append(...)` opens and closes file every time.

Comment: This is even faster then... I will look into this when I have time many many thanks :)

Comment: this just took 15s :o thank you daggett

Answer (score 1):

If `data` was a set. You search at each randomization in the array, that has a complexity of O(N) and searching in a set has a complexity of O(1).

Doing N + c randomizations (c = the number of duplicates at randomization) is by itself an O(N) complexity, so if we consider only this aspect and ignore everything else from the time being, then you have an O(N^2) algorithm that can be reduced to an algorithm of O(N) simply by switching to sets.

You should also get rid of the console prints if possible. Those are costly operations. The same goes for file writing.

You should cache the latest few numbers and store them into your output file. Maybe 100 numbers. And then you can also write into the console that those numbers were added.

Comment: Thank you @Lajos - I will try caching for the file writes :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @daggert was accepted but it doesnt meet my requirements. When tried it gave numbers like `1` where I needed a set size. It's accepted because I wasnt clear on this, and honestly works like a charm. I used the file writing parts mixed with the sets code I had written and this does what I need in under 20 seconds now.

```
int amountToGenerate = 10_000_000
int range = amountToGenerate*2
Set data = []
Random randoms = new Random()

while (data.size() < amountToGenerate){
    int number = randoms.nextInt(range)+amountToGenerate
    data.leftShift(number)
}

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def writeToFile(Set<Integer> data, String path){
    new File(path).withWriter("UTF-8"){w->
        data.each{i-> w.append('83').append(i.toString()).append('\n')}
    }
}
writeToFile(data, /c:\temp\out.txt/)
```

Comment: So you want only 8 digit numbers between ten million and twenty million?

Answer (score 0):

Just around 14 seconds on my Core i5 with 8Gb RAM to create the 40Mb file of numbers. If you need them as text, it might be better to recreate them as text as you need them.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class Rands {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final int NUMBERS = 10_000_000;
        final int MAX = 20_000_000;
        final int MIN = 83;
        Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>(MAX - MIN);

        SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
        while (numbers.size() < NUMBERS) {
            numbers.add(r.nextInt(MIN, MAX));
        }

        Path pathToWrite = Path.of("numbers.bin");

        try (FileChannel fileChannel = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(pathToWrite,
                EnumSet.of(StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING))) {

            MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, numbers.size() * 4);

            if (mappedByteBuffer != null) {
                numbers.stream()
                    .forEach(n ->mappedByteBuffer.putInt(n));
            }
        }
    }
}
```